# How to achieve the below requirements in sql

Tags: sql

[image]I have table like below

the result set should contain 4,5 since it has count of (c2) and (c3) >1

Comment: Why have you changed your request? Please don't do this. You have got several answers to your question. Now if there is one more column involved, then use the given solutions and modify them according to your real needs. Don't be so lazy. Besides you should come here with a concrete problem, which should usually include your own query and a description where you got stuck. Don't have others do all the work for you. And then, you have been asked a question (see jarlh's comment). If you want help then make the "effort" to answer our questions.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.col2 = t.col2 and t1.col1 <> t.col1);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JOIN` a subquery that returns the duplicated col2 values:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
join (select col2 from tablename
      group by col2 having count(*) > 1) t2
    on t1.col2 = t2.col2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by c2) as c2_cnt,
             count(*) over (partition by c3) as c3_cnt
      from t
     ) t
where c2_cnt > 1 and c3_cnt > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you changed your requirement so i changed my query

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 where 
    exists( select 1 from table_name t2 where t2.col2=t1.col2
                                and t2.c3=t1.c3
                              group by t2.c2,t2.c3
                              having count(*)>1
              )
```